# Is it possible to see all three endings in one playthrough?

Tags: the-talos-principle

The Talos Principle has three different endings depending on whether you

> complete all of the main puzzles, finish tower level 5, or collect all the grey sigils and finish tower level 6

If I do one of these endings, is it possible for me to continue the game where I was just before, and do the other endings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The game progress is saved automatically after each sigil/star found. So you can rewind it a little bit back. Check out your menu.